# Uncaught Reference error in $(document).ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel-5, jquery-validate

I am using laravel 5.3. I am trying to validate form data with jquery validate plugin. After data validation I want to fire an Ajax call. Here is my code

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-tagging.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-tagging.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/js/tapered.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/validation.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            function ajaxCall() {
                console.log("event occured");
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '/storeproject',
                    data: { _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}" },
                    success: function( msg ) {
                        console.log(msg);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form role="form" method="POST" action="javascript:ajaxCall()" id="test-form">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <label>Project Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="projectName" placeholder="Name" name="projectname" type="text" autofocus="">
    <input type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hit the add button gives me the error

> VM681:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: ajaxCall is not defined
>       at :1:1

but if I avoid the document ready function it works fine. What is the problem?

the validation.js file is here

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#test-form").validate({
        rules: {
            projectname:{
                required:true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: gives the same error

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions#Function_scope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  // Initialize form validation on the registration form.
  // It has the name attribute "registration"
  $("#test-form").validate({
     rules: {
      projectname:{
          required:true
      }
    },
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/storeproject',
            data: { _token: "{{"+$('#projectName').val()+"}}" },
            success: function( msg ) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="_token" content="{!! csrf_token() !!}"/>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap-tagging.js"></script>
    <link type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap-tagging.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="/js/tapered.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.15.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
   
</head>
<body>
<form role="form" method="POST" id="test-form">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}
    <label>Project Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="projectName" placeholder="Name" name="projectname" type="text" autofocus="">
    <input type="submit"  id="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @MutasimFuad  glad to help you :):)